# __STDC_VERSION__ not defined in C++11?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I tried to get `__STDC_VERSION__` with gcc 4.8 and clang, but it just not defined.
Compiler flags:

`g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b650c0f2cb87f26d

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << __STDC_VERSION__  << std::endl;
}
```

As result:

`main.cpp:6:18: error: '__STDC_VERSION__' was not declared in this scope`

I have to include some header, or add compiler flags?

Comment: About your P.S., Boost, though probably 1.56.0 for that one.

Comment: @chris You mean, Boost have generic lambdas, or Boost can detect does compiler support generic lambdas?

Comment: Boost has all kinds of compiler support macros, but IIRC, Phoenix is generic.

Comment: Why would you expect a C version macro to be defined in C++?

Comment: @chris What is Phoenix?

Comment: @DrewHall Emm.. I don't know. Is that for C only? And have some very special one for C++? I just read about it there https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html

Comment: @tower120, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Your link says "This macro is not defined [...] when compiling C++ or Objective-C."

Comment: @chris I don't see generic lambdas there. And I can't imagine how it can be realized, while C++ not allow any templates inside structs, inside functions.

Comment: @tower120, Look through the examples. What do you call `std::find_if(c.begin(), c.end(), arg1 % 2 == 1)`?

Comment: @chris Can you give me a link?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/starter_kit/lazy_operators.html

Comment: @chris According to this http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/phoenix/example/lambda.cpp "lambda" still call functions defined OUTSIDE function scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) states:

> `__STDC_VERSION__`
>
> ...
>
> This macro is not defined if the -traditional-cpp option is used, nor when compiling C++ or Objective-C.

Also, the C++ standard(s) leave it up to the implementation to define this macro or not, and g++ opted for the latter.

Depending on what you're trying to do the `__cplusplus` macro might be an alternative (it is not just defined, it has a value, too ;)

Comment: That is awesome.  All this time I've seen this macro and never known it had a value of than 1 (or simply was *defined*; i.e. `#define __cplusplus`).  gcc, at least, seems to define this as the *supported language revision in use*.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For those who come across the following warning:

```
warning: "__STDC_VERSION__" is not defined
```

This is due to the `-Wundef` flag which is enabled:

> `-Wundef`
>
> Warn if an undefined identifier is evaluated in an #if directive. Such identifiers are replaced with zero.

(from [official GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wundef))

So you can just define `__STDC_VERSION__` to zero (`-D__STDC_VERSION__=0`) to suppress these warnings.